# MySQL Python connector showing error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I just installed MySQL Python connector 2.0.2 on Windows 7 machine for Python 2.7. I tried to run a sample code to create a connection to my database but it's throwing an error message. "Failed parsing handshake; end byte not present in buffer". I run the following code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
  cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott',
                                database='testt')
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exists")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
  cnx.close()
```

I am using Python 2.7.3 and MySQL server version 5.5.8 . Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Is your MySQL server running?

Comment: Yes, it is running. I checked it with the same username as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without Exception handing, the code to connect to a MySQL database will be :

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='********',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='mysql')
print 'Connected'
cnx.close()
```

[image]

Now, things you need to modify:

1. Change the user to root
2. Enter the MySQL root's password
3. Add the parameter host

You need to use this connector [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)

Comment: 1. I changed the user to root and put root's password
2. I have added new parameters: host and database

But it's still not working. I am not sure whether there is any bug in connector(for Windows). Which python version you are using?

Comment: Python 2.7.5+. I suggest you to shift to Ubuntu

Comment: I can't shift to Ubuntu. But I can change my Python version if needed. Is there any solution for Windows?

Comment: See the edit. And if possible update your python version

Comment: I had downloaded the same connector which you mentioned. I will update my python version and see whether it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can upvote and accept my answer if you feel it is answering your queries

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be specific to MySQL version 5.5.8.  Try upgrading your MySQL version and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, try MySQLdb instead of mysql.connector should fix the issue. And no code changes need for me, it is amazing.